# bash: /path/.bash_aliases: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, chmod

I don't know why this line appears first when I open my gnome-terminal.

```
bash: /home/username/.bash_aliases: Permission denied
laptop-dell:-$
```

I tried this but still the problem remains there.

```
chmod +x ~/.base_aliases
chmod: cannot access `/home/username/.base_aliases': No such file or directory
```

What should be the default permission of 'bash_aliases' ?
How to fix this ?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't *literally* say `/path/`, and that you made it up for the question, i.e. that the path is not the problem?

Comment: Default permission should be `-rw-r--r--` same as `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: @jos doubt it. ... Vipul: please provide the actual commands and errors. If these are it ... "path/" ...  ?

Comment: @Jos, Yes, you are right, I just made it for the question. that's not the real problem.

Comment: @VipulBhatt Please just change the username if you don't want to show your real username, otherwise it ends up being rather misleading for people reading the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the right command and file names **;)**, in your second command is a typo: `~/.bash_aliases` and not `~/.base_aliases`

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.bash_aliases
```

and so I can sleep peacefully (thank you [@ByteCommander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander))

```
chmod 644 ~/.bash_aliases
```

---

And maybe it's time to correct the permissions for the whole folder:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

Comment: Maybe you should not just `chown` it but also set the correct permissions, depending on what got messed up... `chmod 644 ~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes, you're right.

Comment: Hello @A.B.,  My terminal is not opening after performing these commands !!!

Comment: Switch to TTY1 via Ctrl-Alt-F1  and login. What is the output of `echo $USER` (Back to your GUI via Ctrl-Alt-F7)

Comment: My username, @A.B.

Comment: why aren't the perms 755?

Comment: @chicks executable rights are not necessary.

Comment: @VipulBhatt this has nothing to do with the command in my answer. Start the last command again in tty1

Comment: As in my case i was using the wrong "command", as i was having `$Editor` instead of `$EDITOR`

Answer (score 1):

I do a similar thing in my .bashrc file.  I use this compound statement and it works:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
   source ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

The key is the `source` command.  I don't know if this is "bad form," but it works.